# How to import all databases sql file into phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

I have exported all databases (localhost.sql) from phpmyadmin. Now I am trying to import all database file (localhost.sql) using command
mysql -u root -p < /localhost.sql

this is showing error as No database selected.

Localhost.sql has all database, i dont have any other backup of databases except localhost.sql file.

Comment: If u know all the database names , than just recreate all database with same database name and then do import, it worked for me ,may this also works for you

Answer (score 1):

Because when you export file into phpMyAdmin there is no database name. If you want it, when you export click "Custom" in the section export method and tick "Add CREATE DATABASE / USE". Or add at the top of your localhost.sql :

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `NameOfYourDataBase` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `NameOfYourDataBase`;
```

Or the method I use : I export, i drop/delete everything and i recreate a DB with the same name THEN I import the localhost.sql

Answer (score 0):

These information will useful to you.

Only one database backup:

```
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -pmypassword databasename > databasename.sql
```

or

```
 mysqldump database_name > database_name.sql
```

Multiple databases can be backed up at the same time:

```
mysqldump --databases database_one database_two > two_databases.sql
```

It is also simple to back up all of the databases on a server:

```
mysqldump --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

Thank you..